# Crystal Reports/C# - Page N of M not working

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a label that looks like this:
[image]

I have the Page N of M special field added in Crystal Reports and I have this in my C# to print the label:

```
label.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printerName;
label.PrintToPrinter(int.Parse(printQtyTextBox.Text), false, 0, 0);
```

My problem is that if I put 2 or 3 or anything in the box it prints that many labels but every one shows Page 1 of 1 on the top rather than 1 of 2 or 1 of 3.  How do I set that quantity field on the Page N of M?

Comment: `Page N of M` does not count the total number of pages to print (including copies) but only the total number of pages in the document (which may be printed multiple times, as you can see). The number of copies may be passed by an external field (and you can then calculate the total number of pages in the way you want) but the _absolute_ current page number AFAIK is not available. Also note that when someone selects to print X copies then the expected behavior is to print X **exact copies**.

Comment: Ahhh... I will check into that way then.  I thought maybe the N of M used the value you were printing.

Comment: Note that expected behavior when selecting the number of copies is to print N **exact copies** (try it with any application, from notepad to word). You can print multiple pages in the report (repeating one page multiple times) and achieving the desired behavior but you  have to change report content for that

Comment: I know how to get the last number by using the number in the textbox but how do I get the number to increment is the issue I'm having.